# Starting an intent from a list activity which has a onListItemClick implemented

Tags: android, listview

After reading many topics on how to do this I still have this issue occurring. This issue is that the onListItemClick method will not start the activity. The activity is registered in the manifest file. The method works with a toast, but when a start intent is called a error occurs.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {

  super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  Log.i("DebugMessage", "clicked an item..");
  Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Getfiles.class);

// startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  Sometimes starting activities inside onclick listeners can be a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (I think) is that you are using the wrong context to start an intent one of the following solutions should work.

You can try using:

```
new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Getfiles.class);
```

Or

```
private final Activity activity = this;

protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("DebugMessage", "clicked an item..");
    Intent i = new Intent(activity, Getfiles.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it is till not working, the error I am getting on the avd is it force closes and on the ddms there is a runtime exception java.lang.null pointer exception.

Comment: there is no line number but it says at the point of starting the activity.

Comment: If you doubleclick the error in logcat/ddms (in eclipse) you will automagically go the line with the NPE
startActivity(i) won't be the problem because i can't be null, so then one of the params in the intent creation is null
can you post your manifest and some more code of the activity? (pastebin if you want)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can use a Handler, and post a Runnable that will start the activity. This will delay the activity open until after your onListItemClick method returns, and should work fine.

Do it like so. Add a Handler to your class (create it at onCreate):

```
private Handler _handler;

_handler = new Handler();
```

And in your onListItemClickMethod use this:

```
_handler.post(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        startIntent(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: could you give an example of how I might achieve this please? thank you.